# Call a function in another one in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, file

My matlab code has a main file and several function m. files and all the functions have input and output parameters. Some of functions will be used both in the main file and in some of functions but the functions are not konwn in other functions. What should I do?
 Is it possible for a function tu be a nested function in entire code and several files?

Comment: Please provide a code sample which doesn't work, functions should work inside of other functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mean that functions have access to other functions scope in matlab?